# Editing Documents (DOC, DOCX, RTF, TXT) in Webforms

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, components, text-editor, document

I'm developing a web application using asp.net 3.5. This application has a lot of documents like .doc, .docx, .rtf, .pdf, .txt, etc... and sometimes the usar need to edit this documents. As a good web application the user need to download the file, edit it and upload again to the server.

I would like to know if is there any way (a component) to make a editor (like MS Word) in webform that allow the user edit the document and save it on server ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use a Silverlight based text processor (like Nevron Rich Text Editor) or other similar control to do the job...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) protocol to achieve this, which is an extension of the HTTP protocol that allows documents to be downloaded, locked and uploaded and can be kicked off from your Webforms app.

There is quite a mature open source project for .net that you can build upon for your own implementation at http://sourceforge.net/projects/webdav/ with an example webforms project and the code for the server (ignore the comment about there not being source code it's incorrect)

Answer (score 1):

For editing Office docs on a server, there is [Office Web Apps](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps/). For business scenarios, this requires SharePoint Foundation 2010, which is free with a licensed version of Windows Server.

For non-office documents (PDF), you will need to find another solution for each one, since they are application-specific.

Comment: How can I integrate it with Office web apps and asp.net ? Do you recomend something? I found the TX Text Control in web, and I think it's a good solution, have you seen that ?